# inverse laplace tranform

Tags: transformation, laplace-transform

I have a simple question,

There are some functions $f(t)$, $g(t)$ and lets say $F(s)$ and $G(s)$ for the form of Laplace transform of $f(t)$ and $g(t)$, respectively.

While I am solving differential equation with Laplace Transform,

I got this relationship

$$F(s)=\frac{f(0)}{s + G(s)}$$

how can I solve in terms of $f(t)$?

I looked up the convolution theorem but it is not a form of $f(t)*g(t)$

please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without knowing the form of $G$ the best you can do is the inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: how to inverse Laplace transform of F(s)? 

can I write it just like this ?

Comment: $$f(t)=f(0)*e^{-K(s)t}$$

Comment: No. It is not that simple.

Comment: could you give me some hints or could you show me the some steps ?

Comment: See my first comment.

Comment: you mean I should use the definition of the inverse laplace transform ?

Comment: $$F(s)=\int{e^{-st}f(t)dt}$$?

Comment: Your formula above has disappeared. I have no idea what you are hoping for.

Comment: Can you post the differential equation?